# VBA counter based on date

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a userform to track service requests and I am having trouble with this last part.

There are 2 columns in question the first "A" is service ID the second is "B" Date. I want "B" to be today's date and "A" to start at 1 and count up, when I add a new request tomorrow I want "A" to start at 1 again.

Here is the code for column "A", when a new record is created "A" goes up but when the date changes it does not start back at 0. Any ideas?

```
'Service ID
'check row above
'if "Date" then out put "1"
'if yesterday then out put "1"
'if today then ouput + 1

If (Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Value) = "Date" Then
 serviceorder = "1"

ElseIf (Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Value) < Date Then
 serviceorder = "1"

ElseIf (Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Value) = Date Then
 serviceorder = (Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Value) + 1

Else
End If
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just make column A a `COUNTIF` formula to show the number of times the date in the corresponding column B cell shows up in all of column B? That way when the date changes, it will auto reset to 1 and each new time a request is entered the same day, it the ID will increment by 1.  The VBA formula would be:

```
With Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    .Formula = "=COUNTIF(B:B,B" & .Row & ")"

    'Uncomment this next line if you want column A to contain values instead of formulas
    'If you do uncomment it, make sure you have already put the date in the B column for this entry
    '.Value = .Value
End With
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the general problem in your functions is the `Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp)`. Rows.Count means - as it says - the count of rows in your sheet and is 1048576. In my opinion you take the very last cell of the column and `End(xlUp)` won't make it better. I think `Sheet1.Cells(1, "B").End(xlUp)` should work better. Sorry if I'm wrong for I can't reproduce your scenario here.